# How to use the LIKE operator in a C# Command?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-like

I need to insert a string into an Sql Command

```
search.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name like ' + @person + % + '";
```

What it the right way of using `LIKE` in a command?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? MySQL, SQLServer,..?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Should be:

```
SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name like @person + '%'
```

`@person` is a parameter - you don't need single quotes around it. You only need to concatenate it with `%`, which should have quotes.

Keep in mind:

- You could have kept it `"SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name like @person"`, and have the parameter value contain `%` (concatenate in C# is simpler to understand).
- You may also want to escape other wildcard characters already in the string: `%`, `_`, `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 3):

Use Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name LIKE pattern
```

The `"%"` sign can be used to define wildcards (missing letters in the pattern) both before and after the pattern.

For Example:

- `LIKE '%xy'` would get you anything ending with 'xy'
- `LIKE '%xy%'` would get you anything contains the 'xy'
- `LIKE 'xy%'` would get you anything starting with 'xy'

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you mean?

```
searchPerson.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name LIKE '"+person+"%'";
```

Comment: This is open to an [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack! Oh, my!

Comment: Hehe yes it is. Should probably have mentioned that in the answer. I'm gunna use the 'get it to work, then fix the security' excuse :)

Comment: That's why I used parameters LOL

Answer (score 1):

```
searchPerson.CommandText =  
   "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name like @person + '%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
searchPerson.CommmandText = "SELECT * FROM Contacts WHERE Name like '" + @person + "%'";
```

Comment: The will probably not compile, unless there is actually a *variable* called `person`. (coincidentally, `@` is valid before C# identifiers - lucky!). Either way - you change a parametrized command into a potential security risk: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Contacts WHERE Name like '%' + '"+@person+"' + '%' 
select * from Contacts WHERE Name like '%' + '"+@person+"' 
select * from Contacts WHERE Name like '"+@person+"' + '%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
"Select *  from customer where FirstName LIKE '"+TextBox1.Text + '%'+ "'   ";
```

Answer (score 0):

if Field type is Nvarchar use this code:

```
   "select * from Contacts where name like N'%"+person+"%'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for reference!

```
 string strQuery = "select Ac_Key from AccountDetails where (Ac_Name like '%'+@Ac_Name+'%');
 SqlCommand cmb1 = new SqlCommand(strQuery);
 cmb1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ac_Name", AccountName);
```

Answer (score -1):

"SELECT * FROM table_name like concat(@persons,'%')"

I used it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Thanks for your answer, but a bit more explanation than "I used it" would be better