# WHERE (option1 || option2 || ...) LIKE '%key%'

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I wanted to make a query using LIKE.

I don't know what the right syntax for this

```
WHERE ( (option1 || option2 || option3) LIKE '%key%' ) AND field = 'option4')
```

Can anyone help me how to correct this?

I need to make a query WHERE option1 or option2 or option3 are LIKE with the key

after that LIKE condition, I need another WHERE which field = option4

NOTE: option1,2,3... are fields

Comment: (option1 like '%key%' or option2 like '%key%' or option3 like '%key%') AND field ='option4'                                       this will do the thing

Answer (score 3):

You need something like this:

```
where (option1 like '%key%' or option2 like '%key%' or option3 like '%key%')
  and field = 'option4'
```

Comment: yes I did that and that works, but is there a way to make the code not that long?

Comment: @IvorySantos yes - to have fewer options... :)

Comment: @IvorySantos: I can't think of anything. You shouldn't worry too much about how long your SQL is, express your intent as clearly as possible and everyone (you, the people reading your code in six months, and the database) should be happy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Manual (Pattern matching)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html), and the [Like Operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)
and take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12399682/395659), it in general how the Like operator works.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE CONCAT_WS(' ', option1, option2, option3) LIKE '%key%'
  AND field = 'option4'
```

The `' '` can be any delimiter you like, and probably should avoid anything that might cause false readings with `key`.

```
INDEX(field)
```

would probably be the best index.  Indexes on `option1`, etc are useless.

My `CONCAT` is probably a little faster than the `OR` suggestion.